# SQL Trigger after update on a single column in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i'm creating a SQL trigger which I need to insert a record into a different table after updating it on the first table.

I got the following tables.

Queue table:

[image: Queue table]

Bin table

[image]

Till now i've the following SQL query which doesn't compile.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MoveBinToQueue
    ON dbo.Bins
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(Status_StatusId)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Queues
    (
        Prio,
        Time
        Bin_BinId,
        Goal_GoalId
    )
    SELECT
         20,
         GETDATE(),
         inserted.Status_StatusId,
         inserted.Goal_GoalId
         )
END
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You need to specify the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `FROM` clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MoveBinToQueue
    ON dbo.Bins
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(Status_StatusId)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Queues (Prio, Time, Bin_BinId, Goal_GoalId )
            SELECT 20, GETDATE(), inserted.Status_StatusId, inserted.Goal_GoalId
            FROM inserted;
    END
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, the FROM did it for me. You know if it's possible to specify the conditions of the IF. Like  IF UPDATE (Status_StatusId = 6) ?

Comment: Be careful - "if update" does not do what you might assume. It does not look for a **change** in the value, just that the column was included in the update statement. A statement like "update dbo.Bins set Status_StatusId = Status_StausId ..." will return TRUE. You can argue that you would never do this. Unfortunately, both developers and frameworks are often lazy and don't try to avoid unnecessary updates.

Comment: I guess you could do `FROM inserted i where i.Status_StatusID = 6` or something